# Deleting a record with child items and a self-referencing constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, entity-framework-5

So I have the following tables (with irrelevant columns omitted):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Step]
(
   [StepId] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
   [ParentStepId] INT NULL,

   CONSTRAINT [FK_Step_ParentStep] FOREIGN KEY ([ParentStepId]) REFERENCES [Step]([StepId])
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StepInput]
(
   [StepInputId] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
   [StepId] INT NOT NULL, 
   [ChildStepId] INT NULL,

   CONSTRAINT [FK_StepInput_Step] FOREIGN KEY ([StepId]) REFERENCES [Step]([StepId]), 
   CONSTRAINT [FK_StepInput_ChildStep] FOREIGN KEY ([ChildStepId]) REFERENCES [Step]([StepId]),
)
```

There is a Step, which has zero-to-many StepInputs. The StepInput has an optional child Step, and the Step has an optional parent Step (self referencing).

This works as expected. What I want to be able to do now is to delete a Step, and have all of the StepInputs associated with that Step also be deleted, as well as any child steps and their inputs.

I am using Entity Framework 5. Is there a convenient way to do this with EF, or do I need to create a Stored Procedure, set cascade options on my FK constraints, or is there something else that would be a better solution?

I did try using ON DELETE CASCADE in various ways, but nothing I tried worked. I also read that you shouldn't rely on cascading deletes when it comes to hierarchical data, but didn't really understand the alternatives that were suggested (CTEs?)

Would it make things simpler if I nixed the ParentStepId column? It's only real utility now is to determine if the step is a top-level step, which I can probably just as easily use a bit field for. There are no parent-child relationships that don't involve a StepInput in between.

I am obviously pretty green when it comes to SQL in general and SQL Server in particular, so bear that in mind with your answers ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried and created a simple procedure to remove all your rows given a stepId

```
DECLARE @stepId int
SET @stepId = 1

DECLARE @Delete TABLE
(
  id int
)

;WITH IdsToDelete (id)
AS (
  SELECT ChildStepId
  FROM StepInput
  WHERE StepId = @stepId
  UNION ALL
  SELECT s.ChildStepId
  FROM StepInput s
  INNER JOIN IdsToDelete I ON I.id = s.StepId
)



INSERT INTO @Delete (id)
  SELECT id
  FROM IdsToDelete



DELETE FROM StepInput WHERE StepId = @stepId OR StepId IN (SELECT Id FROM @Delete)
DELETE FROM Step WHERE StepId IN (SELECT Id FROM @Delete) OR StepId = @stepId
```

The idea is to create a recursive cte and store all your ids to remove and then store them into a declared table, has the cte is will losse its data after the first statment.

then you just have to delete everything where the id is on that table. I've also removed the constrain you have on the step table has that is making all the deletes fail.

I hope I got it right this time, and I hope you understand what I have done in there.

Cheers,

Comment: Thank you. This looks more like what I need. I will give it a whirl.

Comment: I did a quick test and it seems to work. I understand in general terms what you're doing. I will have to study CTEs a little bit to completely understand it, but I guess I really need to do that anyway. At least this gives me a good reference point to look back at. Thanks again.